# Fetch not syncing with for loop

Tags: json, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I am trying to fetch json data from the unsplash api inside of a for loop but it will not sync with the loop.

async function myfunction(){

```
for (x=0;x<=c.length-1; x++){

     await 

  fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos? 
   client_id=123;query=' +   
      c[x].value).then(function(response){

         response.json().then(function(data) {
               //out of sync with for loop
         }
      });
   });  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing both `async/await` syntax with good old `Promise#then` (but without returning the promise to properly chain).

You could try using only `async/await`:

```
async function myfunction(){
  for (let x=0;x<=c.length-1; x++){
    const response = await fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=123;query=' + c[x].value);
    const data = await response.json();
    // do something with data
  }
}
```

If you don't care about the request being sent sequentially, you can instead use `Promise.all`:

```
async function myfunction(){
  const promises = []; // doing it via loop as we don't know what c is
  for (let x=0;x<=c.length-1; x++){
    const promise = fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=123;query=' + c[x].value).then(r => r.json());
    promises.push(promise);
  }

  const dataArray = await Promise.all(promises);
  // do something with all the data here
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  Thank you very much.